# Installing GitHub on Windows

Tags: windows, installation, github

I downloaded GitHub for Windows and I tried to install it. The installation was interrupted with the message:

> windows application validation did not succeed unable to continue.

How can I get around this error and get the installation to complete?

These are the details:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.2.9200.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.34014
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.34243 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.34014 built by: FX45W81RTMGDR
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.34243 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    dfshim.dll          : 6.3.9600.16384 (winblue_rtm.130821-1623)

SOURCES
    Deployment url      :  github-windows. s3. amazonaws. com/GitHub.application
                        Server      : AmazonS3
    Application url     : http:// github-windows. s3. amazonaws. com/ Application% 20Files/GitHub_2_13_2_4/GitHub. exe. manifest
                        Server      : AmazonS3

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : GitHub.application, Version=2.13.2.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=317444273a93ac29, processorArchitecture=x86
    Application Identity    : GitHub.exe, Version=2.13.2.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=317444273a93ac29, processorArchitecture=x86, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.
    * Trust url parameter is set.
ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly Microsoft.Expression.Effects.resources.dll.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [5/15/2015 10:09:29 PM] : Activation of http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application has started.
    * [5/15/2015 10:09:29 PM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [5/15/2015 10:09:29 PM] : Installation of the application has started.
    * [5/15/2015 10:09:29 PM] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
    * [5/15/2015 10:09:32 PM] : Found compatible runtime version 4.0.30319.
    * [5/15/2015 10:09:32 PM] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [5/15/2015 10:10:24 PM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (RefDefValidation)
        - Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly Microsoft.Expression.Effects.resources.dll.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.ProcessDownloadedFile(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.DownloadModifiedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application. ApplicationActivator. ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, using Internet Explorer, and **https** instead of http did it. That is pasting the following into IE:

**https**://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application

I also added the installation executable to my firewall as described here to begin with, but that didn't kill it. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16671390/installing-github-for-windows

So doing all these steps did it. Thanks! and hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

### First

Try this:

1. Open Internet Explorer (Yes, Internet Explorer)
2. Paste this link into IE, and choose Run.
   http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application

---

> Introduction
>
> I have had a similar problem: after 75% of the file was downloaded, it
>   just got stuck. Then 5 minutes later or so, I've received the exact
>   same error message you did. How I've fixed it
>
> As Geogrgios mentioned above, you need to add an exception to the
>   firewall.
>
> ```
> Go to "Control Panel" and click on "System and Security" (make sure that "View by:" is set to "Category" and not to "Large icons" or "Small icons").
> ```
>
> Choose Windows Firewall (the second option in the right menu). Then, "Allow a program or a feature through Windows Firewall" in the
>   left menu will be displayed, please click on it.
>       Click on "Change settings" to add exceptions.
>       Click on "Allow another program ..", which has gotten enabled, and in the new window click on "Browse..".
>       Choose the "GithubSetup.exe" file, press "Open" and then "Add" and "OK".
>       Run "GithubSetup.exe" and hope for the best.
>
> Better instructions (with screenshots) can be found here

From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16671390/installing-github-for-windows

---

### EDIT

Try installing .Net Framework 4.5, then try again

Comment: I have followed your instructions but still after 75% it stops and gives that error message. I have already seen the question in stackoverflow but I think I have a different problem. The error message there is:
        + Downloading http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/Application Files/GitHub_1_0_47_0/msvcp100.dll.deploy did not succeed.
        + The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

My error message however is:  + Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly Microsoft.Expression.Effects.resources.dll.

Comment: have you got .NET framework 4.5 installed?

Comment: No I don't think I have any .Net framework installed

Comment: I've edited it.

Comment: I did and tried again but I get the very same errors.

Comment: ok, try running a Windows Update first